# $A - \lambda I$ surjective for self adjoint $A: D(A) \rightarrow H $, $\lambda \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I want an argument for why this is true, implying that such lambda are in the resolvent set.

I have tried to construct pathological examples in order to understand this fact, but I still don't get it.

I suspect the solution is embarrassingly simple.

Comment: Take a look at the answer I posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2567129/reality-of-the-spectrum-of-unbounded-self-adjoint-operators/2568578#2568578 . The argument goes through for unbounded.

Comment: Thanks, I think I found that after Fred's answer. Forgive me, what do you mean by $N$ in $N(D-\lambda I)$? Is it the null space? Where my intuition is strongly rejecting the result is that the domain of our operator could be very small, and that doesn't affect the fact that ti is surjective.

Comment: Yes, $N$ for null space. The adjoint of $A  : \mathcal{D}(A)\subseteq H \rightarrow H$ is not uniquely defined unless $A$ is densely-defined.

Comment: Ah. I have looked online and the definition of self-adjoint requires a dense domain. Thanks for pointing this out; I was oblivious.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is self-adjoint, then then the spectrum of $A$ is contained in $ \mathbb R$. You can find this result in nearly every book on operator theory.